# How to set up shared folder to docker container docker on windows

Tags: windows, docker

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K7h7.png)

I want to set up shared folder between window and docker container.
But that doesn't work. How to solve that?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

In Settings, go to Shared Drives and add your C: drive. If it is already set to shared, you can try unshare and sharing again (if your password changed, the credentials used to share the drive may no longer be working. It looks like the latest version of Docker will prompt you to update your credentials, but older versions didn't do this).